# how to draw indicators for direction in unity3d using coordinates

Tags: unity-game-engine, geolocation, directions

My friend has been working on a project of a model of a college in Unity3d and Augmented reality. We're also new to Unity.

We want to show directions to the user so that they can go from a particular class room to another with indicators. We have coordinates of our college but still can't find a way to script that.

Comment: So, you need to know where inside the model the user currently is? Good luck with that, you need some way to a) find the user's current GPS location and b) map that to your virtual model space. I doubt it will be easy.

Comment: I think you need to add more detail. As is this question is too vague and undefined to answer.

Comment: The question is clear, but adding some details will help me understand what you have in mind in terms of the Output. Secondly, since you have mentioned Augmented Reality, my second doubt is, are you using any SDK to handle that part?